# Responsive images into Bootstrap (4) columns and srcset/sizes attributes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-images, srcset

Until now, I had a large image and added the "img-fluid" class to it. With this, I could make the image increase or decrease its size depending on the container. The problem is that a mobile device with a CSS resolution of 360px was displaying a 800px image, for example.

For this reason, I want to make images of different sizes so that each device displays an image more consistent with the size of the container on that device.

I have a real example of a web page that I am making. Next, I show you the size of the image based on the resolution at which the image is being displayed:

```
-------------------------------
|    Screen    |   Rendered   |
|  Resolution  |  Image Width |
-------------------------------
| Above 1500px |     680px    |
|    1500px    |     672px    |
|    1200px    |     535px    |
|     992px    |     440px    |
|     991px    |     796px    |
|     768px    |     610px    |
|     576px    |     544px    |
|     414px    |     382px    |
|  below 414px |   < 382px    |
-------------------------------

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-4 pb-2 pb-md-4 pb-lg-2">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11 mx-auto">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <img src="example-image-1-800px.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img src="example-image-2-800px.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
// Bootstrap Breakpoints: 576px, 768px, 992px, 1200px and 1500px
```

Based on this actual test, I conclude that the maximum width my image will reach is 796px! Now I generate my images based on the previous widths:

```
example-image-800px.jpg
example-image-800px-2x.jpg (1600px width)
example-image-650px.jpg
example-image-650px-2x.jpg (1300px width)
example-image-500px.jpg
example-image-500px-2x.jpg (1000px width)
example-image-350px.jpg
example-image-350px-2x.jpg (700px width)
```

What happens now? I have read several tutorials, I have read the official documentation, and it must be that I am stupid, because I am not able to generate an image tag with the attributes **srcset** and **sizes**. I do not understand the tutorials or the official documentation, so I ask you to help me build the image tag with the measures that I have put in the example so that I can understand it and thus be able to do it with all the images on the website that I am doing.

Thank you very much in advance!
Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you try picture html tag?

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="smaller.jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="default.jpg">
    <img srcset="default.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

Comment: I have read that the picture tag is for when you want to show different images or different frames, the art direction method. Still, I don't know how to write the picture tag either, because I have read in the documentation that you have to fill in the attributes media, srcset and sizes as well as the image tag.